# I need output using my sample table, i given description below

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table sample There are six columns with the names

`username_s,creation_time,correctiveaction_s,qualitytype_s,mqmsconfigattrkey_s,objectid_s`

when i

```
select username_s ,creation_time,correctiveaction_s,qualitytype_s,atrkey
from sample
where objectid_s='Aa11'
  and mqmsconfigattrkey_s='11626018'
;
```

then given output first 2 column of my sample table,  becoz both qualitytype_s(R and D) have same atrkey. But i need only R qualitytype_s output. and if only D qualitytype_s  for atrkey like 13464430(atrkey) then i need D qualitytype_s output.
How to get this value can help me please

```
username_s  creation_time            correctiveaction_s  qualitytype_s  atrkey  objectid_s
w201fai     30-NOV-2011 09:14:27 AM  null                D              11626018              Aa11
w201fai     30-NOV-2011 09:14:27 AM  Repaired            R              11626018              Aa11
w201cairh   30-NOV-2011 09:14:27 AM  Repaired            R              13460719              Aa11
w201fai     30-NOV-2011 09:14:27 AM  null                D              13460719              Aa11
w201fai     30-NOV-2011 09:14:27 AM  null                D              13464430              Aa11
```

Comment: i want to get value according to qualitytype_s , fillter data using objectid_s
, mqmsconfigattrkey_s ..when qualitytype_s is D,R for mqmsconfigattrkey_s 11626018 then i want R data from the table

Comment: qualitytype can be R and D or both RD..is it??

Comment: R and D qualitytype in seprate row...if qualitytype is R And D then i want to get R qualitytype for same mqmsconfigattrkey_s

Comment: i think qualityType is more than 2 type's and you want to pull the data when quality type is falling in R or D type. ??

Answer (score 2):

To be clear abouut your question.  You have multiple records for the same grouping columns.  If one of those records has QUALITYTYPE_S = 'R' then you want that one, otherwise the record where the column = 'D'.

So the solution will be something like this:

```
select * from 
     ( select username_s
              ,creation_time
              ,correctiveaction_s
              ,qualitytype_s
              ,mqmsconfigattrkey_s
              ,objectid_s
              , row_number() over ( partition by objectid_s , mqmsconfigattrkey_s 
                                    order by qualitytype_s DESC ) as rn
        from your_table )
where RN = 1
/
```

In other words, select one record for each group of `objectid_s , mqmsconfigattrkey_s`.  Sort records within that group by `qualitytype_s` in descending order, so  'R' ranks above 'D'.

---

Note: if that column can have other values beyond R and D you'll need to add an additional  WHERE clause to the inner query.

Comment: IN MY TABLE qualitytype_s COLUMN HAVE D,R,R,D,D VALUSE , AND FIRST TWO VALUES IN qualitytype_s COLUMN HAVE SAME objectid_s , mqmsconfigattrkey_s...IF mqmsconfigattrkey_s IS SAME FOR R AND D THEN I WANT R OUTPUT

Comment: I know you think you're explaining yourself but you really aren't.   If my solution doesn't give you the output you want please edit your question to include desired result from the provided sample data.